# Layering dropdown menu on top of swf

Tags: html, css

I have tried everything I know to allow the dropdown menu to fall in front of a swf. When hovering over the navbar, the elements lower move down to allow room for the dropdown rather than staying put. I also tried to change the subnav to position:absolute, but it is then placed in front of the header. I do not want to put this as a fixed position as I hope to create a fluid layout with this later on. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/gmchkxvu/2/

**HTML**

`<div id="navMenu" class="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="https://refrigeratorleasing.com/default.htm">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Our Products</a>
        <ul class="subnav">
            <li><a href="#">All Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Availability per School</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li><a href="#">Rent or Buy</a>
        <ul class="subnav">
            <li><a href="#">All Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Availability per School</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Delivery Schedules</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Update Info Form</a></li>
    </ul>
 </div> 
 <div id="slideImage">
   <object  embed data="https://refrigeratorleasing.com/NewMicrofridge.swf" width="838" height="436" align="right">
    <param name=”quality” value=”high”>
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
  </object>
</div>`

**CSS**

`<div id="navMenu" class="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="https://refrigeratorleasing.com/default.htm">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Our Products</a>
        <ul class="subnav">
            <li><a href="#">All Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Availability per School</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li><a href="#">Rent or Buy</a>
        <ul class="subnav">
            <li><a href="#">All Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Availability per School</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Delivery Schedules</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Update Info Form</a></li>
    </ul>
 </div> 
 <div id="slideImage">
   <object  embed data="https://refrigeratorleasing.com/NewMicrofridge.swf" width="838" height="436" align="right">
    <param name=”quality” value=”high”>
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
  </object>
</div>`

I am new to designing and I am very grateful for a site such as this one.
Thanks!!

Comment: What you're looking for is `z-index`. See this example: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_zindex and try changing the negative `z-index` value to positive.

Comment: I only used positive z-index values and they aren't working either.

Comment: Sorry, I have also tried the negative values with no luck.

Comment: z-index only works on absolutely positioned elements. For example: `position:absolute; z-index:1;`

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. When putting the elements in absolute the layout becomes a mess. Thanks for all your help AnchovyLegend!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this technique:  http://blog.slightlymore.co.uk/flash-and-the-z-index-problem-solved/

You will need to change to using the swf object JS instead of the object embed, but it's probably something you should be doing anyway these days.